# Semantic Mediawiki allowing semantic info for non-current page?

Tags: mediawiki, semantics

This sentence provides semantic information on several objects:

"Bob has two sons, Bill and Jim, who married Mary and Katy 
respectively. Bill and Mary have twin girls, Jill and Amanda."

In a normal semantic wiki (eg, semediawiki), you can only give 
semantic information for the page you're on.

Is there a semantic mediawiki that lets you provide information on 
multiple items at once?

Sample syntax might be:

```
Bob has two sons, [Bob:son:Bill] and [Bob:son:Jim], who married 
[Bill:wife:Mary] and [Jim:wife:Katy] respectively. Bill and Mary have 
twin girls, [Bill:daughter:Jill] [Mary:daughter:Jill|] and 
[Bill:daughter:Amanda] [Mary:daughter:Amanda|]. [Jill:twin:Amanda|]
```

(things like [Mary:daughter:Jill|] create a semantic triple, but print 
nothing)

I'm of course aware of 
http://davidbu.ch/mann/blog/2010-03-12/mediawiki-extensions.html but 
that is a little buggy, builds pages in real-time (a little CPU 
intensive), and doesn't have any community support (no insult to 
David, of course).

For efficiency, when you edited the "Bob" page above, it would update 
Bill, Jim, etc. In other words, the wiki could render "Bill" w/ the 
regular number of MySQL queries, not extra ones for semantic 
information.

An alternate approach I considered is creating "data" pages that 
aren't associated with any wiki page. Example:

```
[Bob:text: has two sons, [Bob:son:Bill] and [Bob:son:Jim], who married 
[Bill:wife:Mary] and [Jim:wife:Katy] respectively. Bill and Mary have 
twin girls, [Bill:daughter:Jill] [Mary:daughter:Jill|] and 
[Bill:daughter:Amanda] [Mary:daughter:Amanda|]. [Jill:twin:Amanda|]]
```

The page above would add text to Bob's page, and semantic information 
to Bob, Bill, Jim, etc pages.

The nice thing is efficiency: you could statically render all wiki pages.

I realize there's controversy re whether this would be a good 
thing. For now, I'm looking to do it technically and worry about the 
other stuff later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to pay David to update his extension, maybe he could even make it do what you want it to do.

Semantic mediawiki isn't my specialty, but alternatively you could probably do this with Templates, since they are basically '"data" pages that aren't associate with any wiki page.'